# How to use observable to send multiple request to service class using RxJava Spring Mvc

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, rx-java

I have an Angular2 app which requests Spring boot server for results. WHere server have 100 items then it should devide each into 10 each and send to service method and send to Angular2 as soon as result available and keep on send results for other items as Async . Give me Spring Rest Controller Example with multiple calls to service method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get pagination done at the server end.. while passing the request to the server, you need to provide your pageSize and offset.. (pageSize will be 10 in your case).. the server will respond with 10 data items, offset number (kind of a page number) and hasMore flag which will tell the client if more data is available..

for your next call to server, you need to send the pageNumber and offset you need data for..